# Expression for group wise specific product In RDLC Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

PI item is entered in the piitem table and in the storereceivedItem table each item is received in multiple Challans and multiple lots. When I am subtracting store receive quantity from pi wise item quantity then the first time calculation for a particular item is correct but the next calculation is not correct.

If you look at the above image, you will see that the red marked item is PIQnty (5000-(Net Receive Qnty (2500)) = (Short /Excess) RCV Qnty (2500). It is OK but for the next challan number Short /Excess) RCV Qnty = (2500 - 2000) = 500 will be. Because 2500 was received in previous challan.[image]

This is the expression I wrote for that field.

=(Fields!PIQnty.Value - Sum(Fields!ReceivedQty.Value))

Now I need help on how to write the expression to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Actually I changed the table structure of my database to solve this. Where I have added one column named PIQNTY and am sending the data by calculation in that column.